# How to do subquery in CakePHP 3

Tags: sql, cakephp-3.0

I have question. I want to do subquery with one table (no joins or other). I have that SQL code:

```
select * from 
  (select * from eksplikacja order by id DESC)
t group by ble
```

But I dont know how to it do in CakePHP 3 Query ORM.
Can you help me?

Comment: did you created any model or you simply want to use the query builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the query builder without accessing any model

```
$connection = \Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager::get('default');
$subquery = $connection
        ->newQuery()
        ->select('*')
        ->from('eksplikacja')
        ->order(['id' => 'DESC']);

    $query = $connection
        ->newQuery()
        ->select('*')
        ->from(['t' => $subquery ])
        ->group(['ble']);
```